# Finder Issues, Crashes and Zombie Finder Processes

Tags: macos, mac, finder

Finder has shown, for a few weeks now, the following symptoms:

About 12 to 24 hours after a restart Finder shows refresh issues. That means that new files are not shown, old files however are still visible. This is not happening in all folders either but in a few.
After a few more hours, Finder starts to display no files in the affected folders anymore.

Any of the common refresh tricks (like switching to another folder and then back do not help.

At this point, a Finder restart is in order. However, no matter how I terminate the finder process, it stays around as a zombie process, preventing a re-launch. Below is the output of `ps` showing the zombie process.

```
bash-3.2# ps -lA |grep Finder
  501   350     1     6004   0   0  0        0      0 -      ?E                  0 ??         0:00.00 (Finder)
```

Even a `kill -9 350` does not clear out this process.

In this state, even a clean restart is not possible anymore and I have to do a hard reset.

I have been going through this almost daily for the last week, so given enough hours, I can reliably reproduce it.

So, I have two questions:

1. How do I get rid of the zombie process without doing a hard reset.
2. How do I figure out what is causing the Finder issues in the first place.

**My system:**

Software:

```
  System Version:   OS X 10.10.3 (14D131)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 14.3.0
  Boot Volume:  Macintosh HD
  Boot Mode:    Normal
```

Hardware:

```
  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,3
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.6 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory:   16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: MBP112.0138.B14
  SMC Version (system): 2.19f12
```

Disk Usage:

```
Filesystem                                                 Size   Used  Avail Capacity   iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1                                                 999G   716G   283G    72% 174838352 69146088   72%   /
```

Comment: How much free space do you have?

Comment: 283 GB. I updated the question with details. However, sometime around the time this problem first occured, the disk was completely full.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already tried Disk Utility and if yes, then fsck

Comment: There was so far no reason for me to believe that this is a disk issues, as other programs have no problem accessing the folders in question. Therefore, I have not yet used either of the two.

Comment: From the reports you were able to generate I believe you're more technical than me, but still — given your previous comment and the fact that some things may not seem related but sometimes are, I would try these in the order I mentioned. You have nothing to lose, at least until a potentially more suitable solution arrives. Also: *Always* make sure you have at least 15% free disk space.

Comment: Not sure i should even suggest this: option-click & hold the Finder's Dock icon and select Relaunch.